# If empty set is a subset of empty set is always true , then is empty set not a subset of empty set always false?

Tags: logic

If $\varnothing \subseteq \varnothing$ is always true , is $\varnothing \subsetneq \varnothing$ always false ?

Any proofs ?

Comment: Well. If set theory, or mathematics, or your inference rules, or somewhere along the way, you have an inconsistency hiding, then you can prove that $\varnothing\nsubseteq\varnothing$. But then you can also prove pretty much everything.

Comment: $\emptyset=\emptyset$ so $\emptyset\nsubseteq\emptyset$ false

Comment: The symbol $\subsetneq$ used in the body of the post means "is a proper subset".  It is also the case that the empty set is not a *proper* subset of itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A \subsetneq B$ means that $A \subseteq B$ but $B \not\subseteq A$.

So, in order to have $\emptyset \subsetneq \emptyset$, we would necessarily have
$$
\emptyset \subseteq \emptyset \quad \text{and} \quad \neg(\emptyset \subseteq \emptyset)
$$
which is clearly impossible.

Answer (score 0):

It sure is! $\emptyset\subseteq\emptyset$ is true and $\emptyset\nsubseteq\emptyset$ is false. Proof: there is no elements in $\emptyset$ that isn't an element of $\emptyset$. $\overset{..}{\smile}$